# T4 Output to String

Tags: c#, .net, windows, code-generation, t4

I am new to T4, I want to generate CRUD Stored Procedures, Data access layer, output to string, I am trying to create kind of webservice api to be useful to other programmers also, just input the data, and download zip file.

I have searched a lot but could not find a way to generate output to string, is it possible, any articles, links, a bit of code if possible would be helpful.

Yes, we can also use StringBuilder, but **The question is "T4 Output to String"** please all type of answers are welcome, but try to focus on the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [preprocessed T4 templates](http://www.olegsych.com/2009/09/t4-preprocessed-text-templates/) to return a string instead of generating a file.

If you change the **Custom Tools** property on the file in Visual Studio to **TextTemplatingFilePreprocessor** then when you save the T4 template a class will be generated. This class will have a TransformText method which returns the generated text.

MSDN also has information on [run-time text generation with preprocessed T4 templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee844259.aspx).